# C change udp dns message to tcp and back

Tags: c, networking, tcp, dns, udp

I have two variables: `buf` and `length` (`char buf[BUFSIZE], int length`). `Buf` contains DNS messages sent with UDP protocol and in `length` there is length of that message. Now I need to change `buf` so I can use it with TCP protocol and send it to DNS server and get response and that response change back to UDP protocol.

I know I should add some bytes and then delete some bytes but I really don´t know which one. So please help and please show it in `C` too.

Comment: So `buf` contains a raw ethernet (or whatever) frame? Or just the application payload?

Comment: Buf get by this ´lenght = recvfrom(mySocket, buf, BUFSIZE - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &addr_len)´ and that communication is with dig program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open a second socket of type SOCK_STREAM and then use send() to send the content of `buf`:

```
sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
connect(...);
send( sock, buf, length, 0 );
```

This works because when working with sockets, you usually don't get the protocol headers, just the UDP/TCP payload.

Comment: I tried it but problem is I get 0 length message from dns server. I found something about adding two bytes of length to message from udp but I am not sure.